# Meta is null in Winston-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, winston

I am using winston-mongodb modlue to log the request response.

Logger.service.ts

```
const options = {
    console: {
        db: DB_URL,
        level: 'info',
        format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
        collection: 'logs',
    },
    error: {
        db: DB_URL,
        level: 'error',
        format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
        collection: 'logs',
    }
  };

const logger = createLogger({
    transports: [
        new MongoDB(options.console),
        new MongoDB(options.error)
    ],
});
```

Server.ts

```
server.listen(port, () => {
    logger.info({message:`Server is up and running on port ${port}`, meta: {
        myProp: 'foo'
      }});
   );
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8bd2c726d273004b082ca"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-06-04T09:21:48.835Z"),
    "level" : "info",
    "message" : "Server is up and running on port 4000 HI",
    **"meta" : null**
}
```

I am trying to add meta data to logger. But it is adding null to the result.

Comment: I had same issue but I fixed following this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606854/how-to-use-express-winston-and-winston-mongodb-together?rq=1

Comment: In your MongoDB options add
....
metaKey: "meta"
....

This key should match the key of the object you're sending as meta-data

Answer (score 7):

To get err object stored in the meta (with all its javascript properties), you need to specify :

```
format.metadata()
```

In the createLogger call.

Here is a working sample code:

```
   // Declare winston
    const winston = require("winston");
    // Import all needed using Object Destructuring
    const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston");
    const { combine, timestamp, printf } = format;
    // Export the module
    module.exports = function (err, req, res, next) {
      const logger = createLogger({
        level: "error",
        format: combine(
          format.errors({ stack: true }), // log the full stack
          timestamp(), // get the time stamp part of the full log message
          printf(({ level, message, timestamp, stack }) => {
            // formating the log outcome to show/store
            return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message} - ${stack}`;
          }),
          format.metadata() // >>>> ADD THIS LINE TO STORE the ERR OBJECT IN META field
        ),
        transports: [
          new transports.Console(), // show the full stack error on the console
          new winston.transports.File({
            // log full stack error on the file
            filename: "logfile.log",
            format: format.combine(
              format.colorize({
                all: false,
              })
            ),
          }),
          new winston.transports.MongoDB({
            db: "mongodb://localhost/logdb",
            // collection: "log",
            level: "error",
            storeHost: true,
            capped: true,
            // metaKey: 'meta'
          }),
        ],
      });
    
      logger.log({
        level: "error",
        message: err,
      });
      // Response sent to client but nothing related to winston
      res.status(500).json(err.message);
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
// create new meta object to store in database
    let logMeta={
        stack: err.stack,                       // error stack
        otherInfo: otherInfoData                            // any other info you want to store
    }

// use metadata propery for meta
    logger.error(err.message, {metadata: logMeta });
```

Comment: Or directly using the err object: winston.error(err.message, { metadata: err });

Comment: Yes, we can . @Nelbren

Comment: @Nelbren - Works like a charm as of today :)

Answer (score 1):

OR another way, if you are exporting the function as error middleware (using nodejs, express):

```
module.exports = function (err, req, res, next) {
  logger.log({
    level: "error",
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack,
    metadata: err.stack, // Put what you like as meta
  });
  res.status(500).send("Uncaught error caught here.");
};
```

Comment: thanks @Timbokun, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Specify metadata object explicitly:

```js
logger.error(err.message, {metadata: err.stack});
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> apparently i had the same problem where the meta property in mongoDB transport was null: This is how i fixed it....

```
const winston = require("winston")
const { format } = require("winstone")

winstone.add(new 
winstone.transports.MongoDB({
format:format.metadata()})
```